# Two UIScrollView one does not show content

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I Have 2 UIScrollView:

```
- (void)generateHeadView {

    self.headArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:self.headButtonArray];

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.headArray count]; i++) {

        UIButton *button0 = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        button0 = [self.headArray objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.playerScrollView.frame.size.height*i)+((self.playerScrollView.frame.size.height/2)-button0.frame.size.height/2), button0.frame.size.width, button0.frame.size.height);

        button0.frame = frame;

        [playerScrollView addSubview:button0];

    }

    playerScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.playerScrollView.frame.size.width , self.playerScrollView.frame.size.height * [self.headArray count]);

}
```

and

```
- (void)generateEnemyHeadView {

    self.headArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:self.headButtonArray];


    for (int i = 0; i < [self.headArray count]; i++) {

        UIButton *button1 = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        button1 = [self.headArray objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.enemyScrollView.frame.size.height*i)+((self.enemyScrollView.frame.size.height/2)-button1.frame.size.height/2), button1.frame.size.width, button1.frame.size.height);

        button1.frame = frame;

        [enemyScrollView addSubview:button1];

    }
    enemyScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.enemyScrollView.frame.size.width , self.enemyScrollView.frame.size.height * [self.headArray count]);

}
```

if i remove `[enemyScrollView addSubview:button1];` then 1 UIScrollView show Buttons but when i add `[enemyScrollView addSubview:button1];` then only 2 UIScrollView show Buttons ...

any ideas?

Sorry for my english

Comment: Where are the text views? I see reference to scroll views and buttons but no text view.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake I meant ScrollViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, has a lot of problems of **OOP conceptually**.

**First of all we begin with the problem:**

**You have an array of** `UIButton`. 
The `UIButton`, **can be added on a class** `UIView` (or kind of).
So, **this button**, can have just **1 SUPERVIEW**.

In other words, **if you add the button on the view1, you will see it on the view1; 
but if after you add this button on the view2, you will see it on the view2 and no more in the view1.**

**Would you be able to be in 2 place at the same time?**

Other things..a better code could be this:

```
- (void)generateHeadView {

    self.headArray = [self.headButtonArray copy]; 
    //if self.headButtonArray is mutable use copy otherwise no.

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.headArray count]; i++) {

        @autorelease {
            UIButton *button0 = [self.headArray objectAtIndex:i];

            button0.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.playerScrollView.frame.size.height*i)+((self.playerScrollView.frame.size.height/2)-button0.frame.size.height/2), button0.frame.size.width, button0.frame.size.height);

            [playerScrollView addSubview:button0];
        }
    }

    playerScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.playerScrollView.frame.size.width , self.playerScrollView.frame.size.height * [self.headArray count]);

}
```

For the other is the same. Obviously, you need to have another set of button so you can't use the same buttons in `headButtonArray`..but you need another array of buttons..or change the strategy.

Comment: So i must create another UIButton and NSArray?

Comment: another array of button yes..i don't know what you need to do..but a button is one entity..and you can't add it in 2 place at the same time. So yes, you need another array with other buttons. Please set the answer as correct so we can close the topic.